# Serialize only public properties in creating ServiceModel.Channels.Message

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, message, datacontractserializer

I'm writing an application that communicates with an external web service, which passes all requests and responses through IClientMessageInspector derived class. In order to test it, I need to write a mock, that will take an object that is being sent to web service method, convert it to ServiceModel.Channels.Message, and pass to this inspector class.

Object is typical WSLD autogenerated class, that looks like this:

```
public partial class CreditInquiry : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private InquiryHeader inquiryHeaderField;

    private IndividualInquirySubscriberCategory subscriberCategoryField;

    [...]
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public InquiryHeader inquiryHeader {
        get {
            return this.inquiryHeaderField;
        }
        set {
            this.inquiryHeaderField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("inquiryHeader");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
    public IndividualInquirySubscriberCategory subscriberCategory {
        get {
            return this.subscriberCategoryField;
        }
        set {
            this.subscriberCategoryField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("subscriberCategory");
        }
    }
    [...]
}
```

In my mock class, I'm generating Message object like this:

```
  var requestType = request.GetType();
  var knownRequestTypes = new HashSet<Type>();
  GetTypesInClass(ref knownRequestTypes, requestType);

  var requestMessage = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Default, "", request, new DataContractSerializer(requestType, knownRequestTypes));
```

GetTypesInClass() method goes through request type, and adds a type of every property and field that is used in it, and request is the object that's being sent to WS method.

As a result, when I invoke ToString() method on requestMessage object, I get following representation:

```
<creditInquiry>
    <PropertyChanged xmlns:d5p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ComponentModel" i:nil="true" />
    <inquiryHeaderField>
      [....]
    </inquiryHeaderField>
    <subscriberCategoryField i:nil="true" />        
</creditInquiry>
```

instead of

```
<creditInquiry>
    <inquiryHeader>
      [....]
    </inquiryHeader>
    <subscriberCategory i:nil="true" />        
</creditInquiry>
```

as I would expect it. So CreateMessage actually serialized private fields of an object, and ignored it's public properties. Can this be circumvented somehow? I'm new to generating Messages manually unfortunately, maybe there are some additional parameters that I need to pass to CreateMessage in order to get desired object representation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the decoration of the element you can specify the attribute name. Change your declaration like this for `InquiryHeader`

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("InquiryHeader", typeof(InquiryHeader), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
```

Comment: I cannot, because it is an autogenerated wsdl class, I don't want to change it.

Comment: If you're not prepared to make any changes then how would you expect the output to change? You'll have to live with it.

Comment: Somehow WCF serializes XML object with only public properties when I execute WS method using autogenerated class. I just want to replicate this logic manually.